# Ordering a Dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to order the dataframe according to the Op.progressPercentage and averaging the eventTimes as in the following:

Input df:

```
uuid,eventTime,Op.progress,Op.progressPercentage, AnotherAttribute
C0972765-8436-0000-0000-000000000000,2017-08-19T12:52:39,P,3.0,01:57:00
C0972765-8436-0000-0000-000000000000,2017-08-19T12:53:18,P,4.0,01:55:00
C0972765-8436-0000-0000-000000000000,2017-08-19T12:53:49,P,5.0,01:55:00
C0972765-8436-0000-0000-000000000000,2017-08-19T12:53:55,P,3.0,01:56:00
C0972765-8436-0000-0000-000000000000,2017-08-19T12:55:07,P,6.0,01:54:00
C0972765-8436-0000-0000-000000000000,2017-08-19T12:55:24,P,5.0,01:54:00
C0972765-8436-0000-0000-000000000000,2017-08-19T12:55:27,P,6.0,01:53:00
C0972765-8436-0000-0000-000000000000,2017-08-19T13:33:46,W,40.0,01:13:00
C0972765-8436-0000-0000-000000000000,2017-08-19T13:40:10,N,51.0,02:00:00
```

Output df:

```
uuid,eventTime,Op.progress,Op.progressPercentage, AnotherAttribute
C0972765-8436-0000-0000-000000000000,2017-08-19T12:52:39,P,3.0,01:57:00
C0972765-8436-0000-0000-000000000000,avg(12:52:39,12:53:18),P,3.0,01:56:00
C0972765-8436-0000-0000-000000000000,2017-08-19T12:53:18,P,4.0,01:55:00
C0972765-8436-0000-0000-000000000000,2017-08-19T12:53:49,P,5.0,01:55:00
C0972765-8436-0000-0000-000000000000,avg(12:53:49,212:55:55),P,5.0,01:54:00
C0972765-8436-0000-0000-000000000000,2017-08-19T12:55:07,P,6.0,01:54:00
C0972765-8436-0000-0000-000000000000,2017-08-19T12:55:27,P,6.0,01:53:00
C0972765-8436-0000-0000-000000000000,2017-08-19T13:33:46,W,40.0,01:13:00
C0972765-8436-0000-0000-000000000000,2017-08-19T13:40:10,N,51.0,02:00:00
```

The Op.progressPercentage should be always monotonic crescent as well as eventTime.
Please, any help on this would be very appreciated. 
Best Regards,
carlo

Comment: `df.sort_values`?

Comment: Sorry, how would you suggest to use sort_values? there is also the need to compute the average of the EventTime. the suggested line of code does not solve the problem.

Comment: What is `avg(12:52:39,12:53:18)` and what is its value?

Comment: Thank you COLDSPEED. Yes, I am going to details avg(12:52:39,12:53:18) as in the following: first it would transform the full datatime in seconds and then compute the mean and transform the result back to a datatime.

Comment: do you see my comment?

Comment: in that case, try `df.groupby`

Comment: Thanks Acushner. How?

Answer (score 0):

```
sorted = df.sort_values(['eventTime', 'Op.progress'])
```

or if you want to modify the dataframe in place,

```
df.sort_values(['eventTime', 'Op.progress'], inplace = True)
```

and if you want to do it backwards

```
sorted = df.sort_values(['eventTime', 'Op.progress'], ascending = False)
```

Comment: Many Thanks Jacob. But your suggestion does not solve the problem described above.

Comment: What you are proposing should use Op.progressPercentage.